# customize arrows of jquery plugin jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I'd like asnwer you if know how customize the arrows of jscrollpane

```
jspVerticalBar .jspArrow
```

Specifically, the size of them, because I'm looking its api, but I dont find nothing like this.

I'm trying through javascript, but when I increase the height of both, I need increase too the height of trackbar and dragbar... but I'm not obtaining it...

For example, I want assign to arrows a height of 36px:

```
var verticalBar = this._htmlElement.children[0].children[1]; //vertical bar
verticalBar.children[1].style.height = this.btsBarHeight+"px"; //up arrow
verticalBar.children[3].style.height = this.btsBarHeight+"px"; //down arrow

//is needed modify track and drag height

//I modify track height
var trackH = parseInt( verticalBar.clientHeight - this.btsBarHeight*2);
verticalBar.children[2].style.height = trackH+"px"; 

//I modify drag height
var dragH = parseInt(trackH-68);
var dragH = (this._htmlElement.children[0].children[0].clientHeight*65)/520;
verticalBar.children[2].children[0].style.height = dragH+"px";
```

This is the offical website of the jquery plugin: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

And this is one fiddle about it: http://jsfiddle.net/gLRYu/68/

I hope your valious help. Thanks in advance, Daniel

**EDIT1**

I update the jsfiddle, clarifing all: http://jsfiddle.net/gLRYu/84/

**The solution of DrColossos works, but I need through javascript**

**EDIT2**

**I obtained it, by modifing the jscrollpane.js , adding a new attribute in settings, called arrowsHeight**. Thanks for your help.

Comment: long time ago i managed to do it with css only

Comment: Yep why not doing it with CSS?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying it, but all the bar is maladjusted

Comment: Give me one minute, I'm going to edit the my fiddle example

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't

```
.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow {
    height: 36px;   
}
```

work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/gLRYu/77/

This seems like what you want and the rest of the scroll bar adjusts nicely to it. If the height gets bigger, the actual scroll bar gets smaller (if this is what you want)

*Update*

http://jsfiddle.net/gLRYu/86/

I don't know, why you set the width of the bar to 100px. I simply set the height of the elements respectivly with.

```
$(".jspVerticalBar .jspArrow").height("36px");
```

Comment: Ok, it seems that works...the issue is that I was doing all through javascript,because I'm working under a javascript project, without css stylesheets

Comment: This is the latest version of my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLRYu/84/ I tried with your solution, and it works, but doing the same through javascript, it doesnt work. Look it please! Thanks very much

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez see my update. Since you are already using jQuery, I simplified your approach with a straigt-forward one.

Comment: Thanks @DrColossos but realize that down arrow is lost